# How to use events in jupyterlab extensions?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I would like to listen to cell events of JupyterLab notebooks (version 3.2.0) in a custom extension. How can I do so?

a) Searching the documentation on "events" did not give helpful information:

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=events&check_keywords=yes&area=default

b) Here is some outdated example I could find:

```
Jupyter.events.on('execute.CodeCell', function(evt, data) {
    // data.cell is the cell object
});
```

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2321

c) Here is another outdated code snipped:

```
require([
    "base/js/namespace",
    "base/js/events"
], 
    function(Jupyter, events){
        console.log("hello2");  
        events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function(){
            console.log("hello3");
        });
        events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
            console.log("hello4");
        });
});
```

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2499

d) I would expect to use something like

```
app.events
```

or

```
var { Events } = require('@jupyterlab/events');
```

However, those variants did not work.

**Edit**

I found another code snippet:

```
panel.notebook.model.cells.changed.connect((list, changed) => {
            if (changed.type == 'add') {
                each(changed.newValues, cellmodel => {
                    let cell = panel.notebook.widgets.find(x => x.model.id === cellmodel.id);
                    // do something with cell widget.
                });
            }
        });
```

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4316

Maybe there is no global "event registry" any more, but the events need to be accessed via the model property?

**Related**:

[Where is a docs for Jupyter front-end extensions JavaScript API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411871/where-is-a-docs-for-jupyter-front-end-extensions-javascript-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JupyterLab Extensions should listen to application-related events using the [signal pattern](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/patterns.html#signals) which is based on lumino [`Signal`](https://jupyterlab.github.io/lumino/signaling/classes/signal.html) implementation.

You can identify the signal of interest in the reference [JupyterLab API Reference](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html) (which is also linked from the documentation as the last entry), for example, cell execution signal is available as [`NotebookActions.executed`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/notebook.notebookactions-1.html#executed).

**Extension Example**

https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/master/signals

**Signals of NotebookActions**

- [executed](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/notebook.notebookactions-1.html#executed)
- [executionScheduled](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/notebook.notebookactions-1.html#executionScheduled)
- [seletionExecuted](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/notebook.notebookactions-1.html#selectionExecuted)

**Signal of observable list**

- [changed](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/observables.iobservablelist-1.html#changed)

**Signals of individual cells**

The cell model provides the signals

- [contentchanged](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/cells.icellmodel.html#contentchanged)
- [statechanged](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/cells.icellmodel.html#statechanged)
- [mimetypechanged](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/cells.icellmodel.html#mimetypechanged)

Usage example:

```
function __observeNotebook(app, dependencies){  

    let notebook = __tryToGetNotebook(app);
    if(notebook){       
        let cellModels = notebook.model.cells
        cellModels.changed.connect(__cellsChanged, this);   

        for(let cellIndex=0; cellIndex < cellModels.length; cellIndex++){
            let cellModel = cellModels.get(cellIndex);          
            __observeCell(cellModel, notebook);
        }

        let notebookActions = dependencies["NotebookActions"];
        notebookActions.executed.connect(__cellExecuted, this);  //selectionExecuted, exutionScheduled
    }        

}

function __observeCell(cellModel, notebook){   
    cellModel.contentChanged.connect(cellModel => __cellContentChanged(cellModel, notebook), this);   
    cellModel.stateChanged.connect(__cellStateChanged, this);   
}

function __cellsChanged(cellModels, change){
    console.log("Cells changed:")
    console.log("type: " + change.type);
    console.log("oldIndex: " + change.oldIndex);
    console.log("newIndex: " + change.newIndex);
    console.log("oldValues: " + change.oldValues); 
    console.log("newValues: " + change.newValues); 

    if(change.type == "add"){
        var newCellModel = cellModels.get(change.newIndex);
        __observeCell(newCellModel);
    }
}

function __cellContentChanged(cellModel, notebook){ 
    let id = cellModel.id
    console.log("Content of cell " + id + " changed");

    let currentText =  cellModel.value.text;
    console.log(currentText);
   
    let cellWidget = notebook.widgets.find(widget=>{
        return widget.model.id == id;
    });

    let outputArea = cellWidget.outputArea;
    let children = outputArea.node.children;
    if(children.length==1){
        let output = children[0];
        console.log(output);
    }
   
}

function __cellStateChanged(cellModel, change){
    let currentText =  cellModel.value.text;
    console.log("State of cell " + cellModel.id + " changed:");
    console.log("name: " + change.name);
    console.log("old value: " + change.oldValue);
    console.log("new value: " + change.newValue);
}

function __cellExecuted(any, context){
    let {cell, notebook, success, error} = context; 
    console.log("Executed cell " + cell.model.id);
}


function __tryToGetNotebookCell(app){   
    var notebook = __tryToGetNotebook(app);
    return notebook
        ?notebook.activeCell
        :null;      
}

function __tryToGetNotebook(app){
    var notebookPanel = __getFirstVisibleNotebookPanel(app);
    return notebookPanel
        ?notebookPanel.content
        :null;
}


function __getFirstVisibleNotebookPanel(app){
    var mainWidgets = app.shell.widgets('main');
    var widget = mainWidgets.next();
    while(widget){
        var type = widget.sessionContext.type;
        if(type == 'notebook'){  //other wigets might be of type DocumentWidget
            if (widget.isVisible){
                return widget;
            }
        }
        widget = mainWidgets.next();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I added some info for my draft answer as you clearly figured it out already. Please modify to your style if you prefer.

Comment: Here is a follow-up question on how to access cell output: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-get-output-model-for-a-given-cell-in-a-jupyterlab-extension/11342/2

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem, thank you so much for your solution! The [signal tutorial](https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/master/signals) is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive reading, including *this* post and @Stefan's [original](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-get-output-model-for-a-given-cell-in-a-jupyterlab-extension/11342) question/post on Jupyter Discourse Forum, as well is [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-codecell/8517) about the `isCodeCellModel()` function, I created the following stub code for handling/manipulating code cell output:

```
import {
  JupyterFrontEnd,
  JupyterFrontEndPlugin,
} from '@jupyterlab/application';

import {
  NotebookActions,
} from '@jupyterlab/notebook';

import {
  CodeCellModel,
  isCodeCellModel
} from '@jupyterlab/cells';

import {
  ILatexTypesetter
} from '@jupyterlab/rendermime';

/**
 * Initialization data for the icode extension.
 */
const plugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'icode:plugin',
  description: 'A jupyter lab/notebook front-end extension for manipulating code cell source and output',
  autoStart: true,
  requires: [ILatexTypesetter],
  activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, latexTypesetter: ILatexTypesetter) => {
    console.log('JupyterLab extension icode is activated!');
    NotebookActions.executed.connect((_, args) => {
      
      const { cell } = args;
      const { success } = args;

      // get type of cell {code, markdown}
      let type = cell.model.type;
      console.log(type);

      // store boolean of whether cell model type is code
      let is_code_cell_model_bool = isCodeCellModel(cell.model);
      console.log(is_code_cell_model_bool);

      // check if cell model type is code
      if (is_code_cell_model_bool) {

        if (success) {

          // if code cell, cast cell model to CodeCellModel for getting outputs
          let codeCell = <CodeCellModel>cell.model;
          let outputs = codeCell.sharedModel.outputs;
          // console.log(outputs);

          // iterate over outputs array of objects
          for (let i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
            
            // console.log(outputs[i]);
            let output_text = outputs[i]['text'];
            let output_data = outputs[i]['data'];

            // check if output_text is defined
            if (output_text) {

              // do something with output_text
              console.log(output_text);
              
            }
            
            // check if output_data is defined
            if (output_data) {

              // do something with output_data
              console.log(output_data);

              // output_data is an object
              // console.log(typeof(output_data));

              let entries = Object.entries(output_data);
              console.log(entries);

              let keys = Object.keys(output_data);
              console.log(keys);

              let values = Object.values(output_data);
              console.log(values);

              // get result from values array
              let result = values[0];
              console.log(result);
              
            }

          }
          
        }

      }

    });
  }
};

export default plugin;
```

It's pretty much self-explanatory and contains some basic comments for unravelling the details.

Even though not directly related to events, I noticed that most questions based on finding the cell model output of a code cell is unanswered.